# Missing space on hdd linux?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, df

```
michaelxu@michaelxu-server:~$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1              71G   65G  2.0G  98% /
none                  495M  224K  495M   1% /dev
none                  501M  104K  501M   1% /dev/shm
none                  501M  376K  501M   1% /var/run
none                  501M     0  501M   0% /var/lock
```

How come the used + available size does not equal the disk size for /dev/sda1?

Answer (score 3):

Linux by default reserves 5% of each partition for the root user. 5% of 71G = 3.55G; 2.0G + 3.55G = 5.55G; 65G + 5.55G = 70.55G which rounds up to 71G.

Comment: With ext3/4 filesystems you can check the amount of reserved blocks with `tune2fs -l /dev/sda1 | grep -i "block count"`.

Comment: hmm sudo df -h results in the same thing though, The missing space is still there

Comment: I'm also not sure I noticed any difference in df output as user or root. Is this distro specific?

Comment: `df -h` will only display information about the current disk (or whatever disk you're pointing to). Linux installers like to make separate partitions for everything, so you won't see everything just by using `df`.

Comment: My mistake; even as root, `df` doesn't show the reserved blocks. @mpy's command will tell you how many there are, though, and that times the block size will give you a number of reserved bytes, which you can then divide by 10^9 and compare against the results of `df -h` to confirm that's where the "missing" space has gone.

Comment: Oh, my bad, thought you were looking for the size of the whole disk. My comment is irrelevant, then. :)

Comment: Perhaps as a side note: Reserved blocks on `/`, `/tmp`, `/var` are vital to keep the system alive when some user (accidentally) fills up the whole disk (minus the reserved blocks). On dedicated data partitions I usually have much less (if any) reserved blocks. Read about `tune2fs -m` in the manpage.

Comment: @mpy An excellent point.

Comment: @BenRichards `df` without a path argument will display information about all mounted filesystems.

Comment: @AaronMiller True. I usually have a `.` by habit.

Comment: It is the ext[234] filesystem, not linux that does this.